# ipysheet.sheet converting to DataFrame with saving manual changes done

Tags: python, pandas, spreadsheet

The aim is to create an interaction dataframe where I can handle values of the cells without coding.
For me it seems should be in the following way:

1. creating ipysheet.sheet
2. handling cells manually
3. converting it to pandas dataframe

the problem is:

after creating a ipysheet.sheet I manualy changed the values of some cells and then convert it to pandas dataframe, but changes done are not reflected in this datafarme; if you just call this sheet without converting you can see these changes;

```
d = {'col1': [2,8], 'col2': [3,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

sheet1 = ipysheet.sheet(rows=len(df.columns) +1 , columns=3) 
first_col = df.columns.to_list()
first_col.insert(0, 'Attribute')
column =  ipysheet.column(0, value = first_col, row_start = 0) 
cell_value1 = ipysheet.cell(0, 1, 'Format')
cell_value2 = ipysheet.cell(0, 2, 'Description')
sheet1
```

[creating a sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOH8Y.png)

```
ipysheet.to_dataframe(sheet1)
```

[converting to pd.DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJc6U.png)

Comment: Did you get any solution to grab manually changed cell data and convert it to dataframe? I am not able to get the manually changed sheet data. @max

Answer (score 1):

Solved by predefining all empty spaces as np.nan. You can handle it manually and it transmits to DataFrame when converting.

Comment: can you please elaborate how you went about predefining all empty spaces as np.nan? was it programmatic or manual. Running into same issue but fix is not clear

Comment: Neat trick. Anything will work, for example ``cell(1, 1)`` (default to 0.) or ``cell(1, 1, None)`` or even ``cell(1, 1, '')``.  ``np.nan`` also works.

Comment: @mikey what do you mean by setting `cell(1,1, None)`, not getting the manually inserted data on the sheet, could you please elaborate here on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71298246/ipysheet-manual-changes-are-not-available-when-converting-it-to-dataframe